# Событие остановки программы в netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Подскажите как в netbeans отловить событие остановки консольной программы, пробовал addShutdownHook, но он не срабатывает при нажатии на кнопку остановки программы.

Comment: Консольное приложение ваше? Доступ к исходникам есть?

Comment: Да там особо нечего показывать, имеется сервер и клиент. Сервер находится в бесконечном цикле, в котором ожидает подключение клиентов. Клиент и сервер обмениваются между собой данными в момент остановки сервера через netbeans объекты содержащие информацию о клиенте должны сериализаваться в файл.

Answer (score 0):

Остановка программы через `netbeans` скорее всего происходит через системный сигнал `KILL -9`. Данный сигнал нельзя обработать средствами `java`, т.к. `jvm` при его получении сразу завершает свою работу.

Для обработки сигналов, кроме механизма hook'ов можно воспользоваться классом `sun.misc.Signal`, но он в данной ситуации тоже не поможет.

Comment: А что тогда поможет?

Comment: Ничего не поможет. Вообще программу останавливать таким образом не корректно, отстреливают сигналом kill -9 только зависшие приложения.